# Watch a select quantity selector with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make a quick shopping cart with on existing project.

My list items is already is generated by php and I get work with html elements like that :

```
const billets = document.querySelectorAll(".card-billet");

var products = [];

billets.forEach(billet => {
    products.push({
        title: billet.querySelector('.card-billet-title').textContent,
        price: billet.dataset.price,
        qty: billet.querySelector('select[name="billet_quantity"]').value
    });
});

const App = {
    data() {
        return {
            items: products
        }
    },
    watch: {
        items: function () {
            console.log("watched");
        },
    },
    computed: {
        total: function () {
            console.log(this.items)

            let total = 0.00;
            this.items.forEach(item => {
                total += (item.price * item.qty);
            });
            return total;
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#checkoutApp')
```

This works but only on page load but I'm trying to change the total when my select quantity changeno.

I'm a bit lost to achieve this, should I use watch but on what ? Or anything else ?

Comment: can you show the part of the code that mutates the `items` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to achieve this, the problem was that my array was out of the vue instance so can't be updated.

I simplified the code like this :

```
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange: function (e) {
            // console.log(this.items)
            this.items = [];

            document.querySelectorAll(".card-billet").forEach(billet => {
                this.items.push({
                    title: billet.querySelector('.card-billet-title').textContent,
                    price: billet.dataset.price,
                    qty: billet.querySelector('.card-billet-qty-selector').value
                });
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        total: function () {
            // console.log(this.items)

            let total = 0.00;
            this.items.forEach(item => {
                total += (item.price * item.qty);
            });
            return total;
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#checkoutApp')
```